# When Subset HTML QLabel, I Cannot Understand Height Behaviour

Tags: html, pyqt, height, subset, qlabel

When I put a QLabel with html Subset in a QWidget I get different type of behaviour depending if the QLabel is in a custom widget or in the main window or in a layout.

The main problem is that not all the rows of the html table show up. The content is chopped in height.

Infact I find it weird that the 'height' attribute is not supported in HTML subset, it would make life much easier.

here is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QRect, Qt

class Labhtml(QLabel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        html = ('''
            <body>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="header_cell" width="200">
                    <div id="ticker"><!--INST.T--></div>
                    <div id="price">   1000.25<!--price--></div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                </td>
                <td id="values_cells">
                    <div id="value">   +0.23%<!--value02--></div>
                    <div id="average"> 0.13%<!--range02--></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </body>
            </html>

            ''')

        label = QLabel(html, self)
        self.setStyleSheet('QFrame {background-color: grey;}')

        self.resize(100, 150)


class Wid(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        self.resize(100, 450)
        Labhtml(self)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)

        layout.setSpacing(0)


class Example(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)

        Labhtml(widget)
        layout.addWidget(Wid(widget))
        layout.addWidget(Labhtml(widget))


        self.setWidget(widget)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Have you tried using QTextEdit ?, I think it is more appropriate for your application

Comment: @eyllanesc damn yes, this is a very good piece of advise, thanks. Dont know why I got stubborn on Labels

Comment: @user3755529. Is this question still relevant? I was able to fix your example so it least looks sane, if you're still interested.

Comment: @ekhumoro I am working with QTextEdit and is going quite smoothly... but if you post the solution it may come handy at some point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a fixed version of your example that seems to work correctly. Hopefully you will be able to see what changes I had to make:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QRect, Qt

class Labhtml(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        html = ('''
            <body>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="header_cell" width="200">
                    <div id="ticker"><!--INST.T--></div>
                    <div id="price">   1000.25<!--price--></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="values_cells">
                    <div id="value">   +0.23%<!--value02--></div>
                    <div id="average"> 0.13%<!--range02--></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </body>
            </html>
            ''')
        self.setText(html)
        self.setStyleSheet('QFrame {background-color: grey;}')

class Wid(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        label = Labhtml(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.setSpacing(0)

class Example(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        layout.addWidget(Wid(widget))
        layout.addWidget(Labhtml(widget))
        self.setWidget(widget)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```